# What is the best git workflow for side-by-side development of "sibling" branches

Tags: git, version-control

While working on a feature branch (`feature-branch-a`) (`feature-branch-a` branched-off of master), I want to make some fix to `master`.

Since I have a lots of changes in `feature-branch-a`, so much that it makes lots of sense to base the fix on `feature-branch-a` rather than on `master` branch, I created new branch `fixture-B` from `feature-branch-a` (since I will eventually merge `feature-branch-a` into `master`). However, I still continue to develop `feature-branch-a` alongside this new branch `fixture-B`. Now merging branch `fixture-B` with `feature-branch-a` results in `Already up to date`, so no 'merge commit' was done (as I intended).

Where did I get this wrong/how is this best handled?

Comment: In case you landed on this SO page via chat, note that I accepted @VonC's answer because his contribution provided more context to what happened. You can check the discussion comments on his answer for specific details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `feature-b` is created from `feature-a`, a merge of a to b would result in a noop: nothing to merge, since the source branch (`feature-a`) is already an ancestor of the destination `feature-b`

```
 a--a--a  (feature-a)
        \
         b--b--b (feature-b)
```

A `git checkout feature-b ; git merge feature-a` won't move `feature-b` HEAD.

A `git checkout feature-a ; git merge feature-b` would update `feature-a` HEAD to `feature-b` (called "fast-forward merge"):

```
 a--a--a  
        \
         b--b--b (feature-b, feature-a)
```

Comment: This doesn't look quite like side by side development: "However, I still continue to develop `feature-branch-a` alongside this new branch `fixture-B`".

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know, but that does look like "I created new branch fixture-B from feature-branch-a" and explain what the OP is seeing: "Now merging branch fixture-B with feature-branch-a results in Already up to date"

Comment: Yeah, one part seems to contradict the other.

Comment: So it means it was my mistake to have branched `fixture-B` from `feature-branch-a` and develop both branches simultaneously? (like if I was thinking like git, I should have rather branched `fixture-B` off of `master` and then doing the mergers will make sense since there will now be a divergent point for `fixture-B` and `feature-branch-a`), right?

Comment: @VonC but your does graph illustration doesn't depict that `feature-branch-a` has moved? (I mean the first graph illustration). The graph looks as though `feature-branch-a` is stagnant and only `fixture-B` moved i.e. 2 commits ahead of `feature-branch-a`! (don't forget I said I was developing both branches side-by-side, meaning while I branched-off and was developing on branch B, branch A was also being developed simultaneously - it never stopped like your graph depicts)

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere It was not a mistake, *but*: you did *not* develop both branches simultaneously: only `feature-b`. Which means, merging it to `feature-a` won't do anything, since `feature-a` has not changed.

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere You need to edit your question with the exact command you have run to merge (and the `git status` when doing that command), in order for us to judge what was merged to what. And double-check the history of the target branch.

Comment: @VonC "simultaneous development" in this context means: some days, I work on A, some other days, I work on B. So every now and then I contribute something to both branch and commit same. Now I'm done and merging gives this "Already up to date" message

Comment: @VonC Unfortunately, I cannot get more details because I had to resolve it manually. I copied branch B's code elsewhere, deleted the branch, recreated branch B off of master, overwrite working tree with the previously backed-up B's code, and then did `git merge feature-branch-a` from B. However, kindly update your answer (especially the graph) to depict/include that the development of `feature-branch-a` and `fixture-B` was going on at same time and remark on what the resulting merge should be so that I be able to mark your contribution as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @VonC for example, to provide more context to your answer, if I had `git merge --no-ff feature-branch-a` from branch B, would I have gotten a merge commit (with those <<<=== conflict markers)?

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere Then you must have "worked on A" in another branch than A, or in a detached HEAD. Because "Already up to date" means: all the commits of the destination (A) are *already* ancestors of the source branch (B)

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere `git merge --no-ff` would have generated a merge commit, yes, but the conflicts markers are only there if you have edited the same section of the same file concurrently in both branches.

Comment: @VonC ..now it's beginning to add up. Thanks for the clarifications. However, you brought up something that I don't quite get: how can I possibly work on A "in another branch than A"? (btw, I sure do have other branches in my local repo other than these branches A and B)

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere Sometime you think you are in a branch, but you are not: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7124486/6309

Comment: @VonC thanks man...I never knew `rebase` can lead to detached head state. I did rebase at a point in time. Now I know better! Thanks again

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere did you complete the rebase? I've never been in a detached HEAD state after a rebase.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I cannot really tell, but from the contributions on this question so far, that is the only explanation I can give. You have now added another context, i.e. incomplete rebase. I won't want to start digging into git log to confirm that. As I previously mentioned above, I have used a semi-manual-ish way to resolve it :)

Comment: Take a look into the reflog as well.