# What does "it’s best not to make any changes to your project when you’ve checked out an old commit" mean?

Tags: git

I'm reading a book Python Crash Course 2nd Edition. In the appendix D devoted to Git there was presented a way to revert back to previous commits using `checkout` command

Commands are:
`git checkout ee7641`

Then this message's supposed to emerge

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
> experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
> you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
> another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
> may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.
> Example:  git checkout -b
>
> HEAD is now at ee7641...

Then to exit HEAD detach state I need to write this:
`git checkout master`

> This command brings you back to the master branch. **Unless you want to
> work with some more advanced features of Git, it’s best not to make
> any changes to your project when you’ve checked out an old commit**.
> However, if you’re the only one working on a project and you want to
> discard all of the more recent commits and go back to a previous
> state, you can reset the project to a previous commit

I don't understand what highlighted part of the text means.
"Unless you want to work with some more advanced features of Git, it’s best not to make any changes to your project when you’ve checked out an old commit"

Does it mean that I can't make any changes after I returned to an older commit? It doesn't make any sense for me

Comment: You can **very well** make changes after checking out an old commit. But this article means that unless you're savvy enough to know how to handle it, it can be a source of confusion for beginners. The described technique (checking out an old commit) is to be considered some kind of observation mode. If you plan to make actual changes from an old commit, it's probably easier to create a new branch pointing at that old commit, rather than working in detached HEAD state.

Comment: Did the checkout actually succeed? Because that message doesn't seem like something which would appear when you check out master ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124486/what-to-do-with-commit-made-in-a-detached-head for reference.

Comment: @Kim The quoted git message is the output upon checking out a commit directly. The paragraph below `git checkout master` is not a git message, it's a quote from the book OP is studying.

Comment: @RomainValeri what do you mean by 'savvy enough to know how to handle it'? What should I specifically know to handle it properly? And what do you mean by 'observation mode'?

Comment: @RomainValeri could you please recommend a good article on this topic (checking out an old commit)? I feel there's some kind of a gap in my git knowledge, because I don't understand much of what you are saying

Comment: For someone with a bit of experience with git concepts, this is trivial. You can work and commit as much as you want in detached HEAD state, then when are happy with how it looks, put a ref on HEAD (likely with `git branch <somename>`) *before* checking something else out. It might look less intuitive than the classic route (creating a branch first then working on it) but it produces the same result.

Comment: By "observation mode" I was just refering to the situation where you want to inspect an older version, without the need to modify it. Lots of good resources in [the tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info).

Comment: @RomainValeri yes, branching looks more intuitive to me for sure, I learned about it. But checking out a commit seems not that understandable

Comment: @RomainValeri but I still don't understand why it's said that I should not make any changes. If I very well can do it, why it's said not to? And what more advanced features of Git is it talked about? Or does it maybe mean that I shouldn't make changes while in detached HEAD state?

Comment: I'm the author of PCC. All I meant with that passage is that if you're only using what's covered in the appendix, then making changes to an older commit will probably lead to confusion. The main purpose of the appendix is to get people familiar with making commits, and then be able to go back to a known working state if they mess up a project. Working with branches is not "advanced", it's just "more advanced than this appendix".