# Where am I? * (no branch)

Tags: git, branch

I've been getting familiar with creating, merging and deleting branches. I like to know where I am so I don't commit work into the wrong branch. I use `git branch -a` to see which branches I have. I think the asterix `*` shows which branch I'm currently on.  What does it mean when I get:

```
* (no branch)
master
origin/HEAD
```

Because when I `$git checkout mybranch` I expect to see

```
* mybranch
master
origin/HEAD
```

Comment: Did you accidentally delete your branch?

Comment: What was the result of `git branch -a`? Did it include `remotes/origin/mybranch`?

Answer (score 4):

The git checkout man page does mention, for the branch name argument:

```
<branch>
```

> Branch to checkout;
>
> - if it refers to a branch (i.e., a name that, when prepended with "`refs/heads/`", is a valid ref), then that branch is checked out.
> - Otherwise, if it refers to a valid commit, your `HEAD` becomes "detached" and you are no longer on any branch.

So instead of having checked out a branch name, you must have checked out a tag name (valid commit), making your **[HEAD a detached one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes)**.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I had a detached head. This was an unknown scenario for me which I over looked in my study of branches. I found all the information I need to fix it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have a branch called `mybranch`. If you want to create a branch that points to the current head, use `git branch foo`.

If you want one that points to another ref, use `git checkout -b newbranch <ref>`