# Git: How to get the name of checked out tag when 2/more tags on same commit

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

1. I have a git commit with 2 tags, like this: `commit1-----tagA,tagB`
2. Checkout "tagA" by `git checkout tagA`
3. **Question:** How to get the tag name of current checkout? I have try `git describe`, but it's always return name "tagB", expect return "tagA".

   Seems `git describe` only be able to return the most recent tag name, see from [git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)

   > The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.
   >   If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown.
   >   Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional
   >   commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of
   >   the most recent commit.

Is there any other method?

**Purpose related this question:**

I want to make file auto build the version number from the tag name, `git describe` work well when 1 commit with 1 tag, but it's not useful in above case.

Comment: In short: There is no easy, straightforward way to determine which tag was checked out; when checking out tags, git automatically goes into a detached HEAD state. If you really want to know which tag was checked out, `git reflog` ([as torek suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28939249/2274224)) is your best bet.

Comment: Does [`git nthlastcheckout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973183/1290731) help?

Comment: Thanks, I have try the `git reflog`, it can provide the right tag name when switch(`git checkout`) from one commit to a tag on another commit; but if switch from one tag to another tag on the same commit, the tag name will not be updated, this looks like a bug. @torek

Comment: @chenchang I don't think that's a bug. The `reflog` maintaines a update history for `HEAD` (or any other reference). When checking out a different tag for the same commit, the checked out commit doesn't change, speaks there was no update. No update, no reflog.

Comment: @Zeeker understood and agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `tagA` and `tagB` point to that one specific commit, so either name is equally good (or equally bad) as far as git is concerned, if you want to check out or look at that particular commit.

The documentation's phrasing "most recent tag" is perhaps misleading here (although it's likely why you get `tagB` as output).

---

#### How to get the result you want

If you want to know what tag-name you gave to `git checkout`, you can either save that yourself, or consult the reflog for `HEAD`:

```
8004647 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to v2.3.1
```

The reflog method has the advantage that it's already implemented; but reflogs are only retained for a while (configurable, default 90 days for reachable references) before being expired away to keep reflogs from growing forever.

---

#### How "git describe" comes up with the answer you didn't want

"Most recent" means that if tags have associated date-and-time stamps—annotated tags do, lightweight tags don't—then those with a later time are considered "better", as described below.

Note that at any time, any git command can easily look up all external references and translate them to SHA-1s.  To see how this works, simply run `git for-each-ref` (you may want to pipe this to a pager like `less`).  The output looks something like this:

```
c2e8e4b9da4d007b15faa2e3d407b2fd279f0572 commit refs/heads/maint
9ab698f4000a736864c41f57fbae1e021ac27799 commit refs/heads/master
[snip]
74d2a8cf12bf102a8cedaf66736503bb3fe88dfb tag    refs/tags/v2.2.0
[more snippage]
```

These are branches and tags—in this git repository (for git itself) all the tags are annotated—and their corresponding SHA-1s.  If there were an active stash it would show up as well (under `refs/stash`).

In any case, suppose that `git describe` has, at this point, one of these commit IDs (an SHA-1), and `describe` has also found two or more names that resolve to that ID.  These may just be annotated tag names, which is what you get without options, or they might be another name (like a branch name) allowed by `--all`, for instance; but the important thing is to suppose that there are two or more names, all all pointing to the same commit.

The `describe` command *could* try remembering *all* of these names, but it doesn't.  Instead, it runs the names through a sort of two-at-a-time tournament to see which one "wins a contest":

- If both names are annotated tags, use the date-stamps on the two names to choose which tag to keep, and which to throw out.  The idea here appears to be that if the same commit is given two or more annotated tags, the one created later is probably "better" and is what `git describe` should use.
- If one name is an annotated tag and the other is not, keep the annotated tag; throw out the other name.  In other words, any annotated tag is better than any lightweight tag.
- If neither name is an annotated tag, but one is a (lightweight) tag and the other is not, keep the tag; throw out the non-tag.  In other words, any tag is better than anything else.
- Otherwise (neither name is a tag of any kind), keep the "earliest-encountered" name (this depends on the internal name-walking mechanisms of git and hence is not necessarily predictable).

Once all the names for this commit have been contested against each other to choose a "winning name", the "winning name" is saved along with the commit SHA-1.

---

Now, how do we get that commit ID in the first place?  The answer is that `git describe` starts with your argument(s):

```
$ git describe       # no args, means ...
$ git describe HEAD  # use HEAD to get the SHA-1
```

Your arguments (or `HEAD`) are turned into the appropriate raw SHA-1 using `git rev-parse` (well, its C code equivalent):

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
9ab698f4000a736864c41f57fbae1e021ac27799
```

Then, `git describe` invokes `git for-each-ref` (or its C code equivalent) to turn all the names you allow it to use—by default, all annotated tags—into SHA-1 IDs.  If any of them match *this* SHA-1, they're saved.  If there are multiple matches, they're run through the contest to pick a single winner.

For your particular case, this part succeeds: both `tagA` and `tagB` are exact matches, so the whole thing stops after picking a winning tag between these two.  In your case that was the tag you *didn't* want.

In general, though, `git describe` often has to keep going.  Consider, for instance, the following commits from the `git` project itself:

```
088c9a8 strbuf.h: format asciidoc code blocks as 4-space indent
aa07cac strbuf.h: drop asciidoc list formatting from API docs
6afbbdd strbuf.h: unify documentation comments beginnings
bdfdaa4 strbuf.h: integrate api-strbuf.txt documentation
eae6953 tests: correct misuses of POSIXPERM
1767c51 t/lib-httpd: switch SANITY check for NOT_ROOT
b4a56a3 "log --pretty" documentation: do not forget "tformat:"
```

Now suppose we make one tag `X` pointing to commit `b4a56a3`, one tag `Y` pointing to commit `eae6953`, and one tag `Z` pointing to commit `aa07cac`.  If we then ask git to "describe" commit `088c9a8`, it could be described as any of the following:

- the commit that occurs six steps after commit `X`, or
- the commit that occurs four steps after commit `Y`, or
- the commit that occurs one step after commit `Z`

The output of `git describe` will use tag `Z`, because it requires fewer steps to go from "tag Z" (commit `aa07cac`) to the commit in question (`088c9a8`).  How this actually happens is remarkably (perhaps unnecessarily, although that's a value judgement :-) ) complicated.

What `git describe` does here is to walk through (part of) the commit graph (applying `--first-parent` if specified) to find a "nearby" commit that does have a name.  The search order is somewhat difficult to describe: it's partly date-based (a la `git log`'s date-sorted commit listings), but it stops early if it encounters an annotated tag.  Otherwise it accumulates a list of "candidate names" (using the contest method described above), stopping when it has accumulated enough (default 10) candidate names, then sorts the list.  The sort is based on "graph distance", so assuming `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are all lightweight tags—if any were an annotated tag it would have been picked by now and the search stopped—`Z` wins here.

Last, having found a name that points to a suitable commit that is not actually the given-as-argument commit, `git describe` prints the name, the number of steps distant ("depth"), and the `g` and part of the actual SHA-1:

```
v2.3.3-220-g9ab698f
```

(though the depth and `g` can be suppressed, and the whole thing can fail if no names at all can be found or if you've asked for exact matches only, and so on).

Answer (score 3):

You can at least get all tags for your given commit:

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

From [`git tag` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

```
--points-at <object>
```

> Only list tags of the given object.

From there, you can extract the one you want.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't notice it when `--points-at` went in (git 1.7.10 based on the release notes).

Comment: Nice option. Thanks you for that. How do I programmatically select the one that was most recently tagged? Say I have 1.3.2 and 1.3.9 tags at the same commit (HEAD). Is there a easy way to have it select 1.3.9 which is what I want and the most recent tag I added?