# Is it possible to automatically replace custom string during git tag?

Tags: git

VERSION variable placed in a file

i.e.:
VERSION='1.0.0'

I want that when a new tag (release) created, somehow git shall replace the value of this VERSION variable to the release/tag name.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in git itself, no.

#### You can't always get what you want

You need to make note of two things here:

1. A `git commit` makes a new snapshot, by taking whatever is in the index / staging-area and turning that into a commit.<sup>1</sup>

   This means that what will be extracted to a work-tree, given some commit, is whatever was in the index at the time.  To make a new, different, saved tree, you must alter the index and then make a new commit.
2. A tag is not a commit.

   Tags come in two forms: "lightweight" tags, which are simply references whose names start with `refs/tags/`, and "annotated" tags, where git adds an annotated-tag object to the repository—this tag object necessarily points to an already-existing commit object<sup>2</sup>—and then a new lightweight tag using the name, pointing to the annotated-tag object.

   Given a tag name, i.e., a reference starting with `refs/tags/`, that tag is "lightweight" when it points to a commit, and "annotated" when it points to an annotated-tag object, which then points to a commit.  Either way, a tag *points to* a commit—some commit that already existed at the time you made the tag.

#### But if you try sometimes, you just might find, you get what you need

Therefore, any file actually stored *in* git, has to be changed (and added to the index / staging-area) at the time the commit is made.  You can thus write a little program that:

- updates the version file;
- commits the update; and
- tags the commit

which will achieve the result you want.

Alternatively, you can design your system so that the version file is *not* maintained through git, and instead is created by the build system, which extracts the version information from git in whatever manner you like.

See these SO questions about using `git describe` for more information:

- [Deriving application build version from `git describe` - how to get a relatively straightforward string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3300746/1256452)
- ["git describe" ignores a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4154485/1256452)
- [How can I use "git describe --match" sensibly in combination with a shallow clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35691922/1256452)
- [Git: How to get the name of checked out tag when 2/more tags on same commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28938968/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>If the new commit would be identical to the current one, and the new commit is not a merge commit, `git commit` refuses to make the commit unless you force it, with `--allow-empty`.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, a lightweight tag, or the hash inside an annotated tag, can point to something other than a commit object.  I have used this for some special hacks in the past, and it works.  It's not something git will normally do though.