# git: branching removed some commits

Tags: git, git-svn, branch

I had a weird situation today.. I'll try and recreate what I think happened.

I wanted to move a speculative change (made to `a_file`) to a new branch and continue working on the main branch without it.

On master with `a_file` and `b_file` **dirty** I did:

```
git checkout -b saved_feature

git commit a_file -m "Putting this modification on a different branch"

git checkout master
```

At this point git complained that b_file was dirty - this was a warning sign but I didn't recognise it.

I was still on branch `saved_feature` so I thought I could do:

```
git stash save

git checkout master
```

So far so good

```
git stash pop
```

At this point I get an error saying that the stash couldn't be merged.

I examine the log - **for some reason there are about 6 days worth of commits that were originally committed to the `master` branch but which were not in the log**. These commits were *only* on the new branch that I had created (I checked in case I had been committing them to a different branch).

After examining the log of the `saved_feature` branch, I can see that they are all there.

What happened?

I next tried on `master`:

```
git merge saved_feature
```

But the fast forward option failed with a ton of conflicts.

I also use git-svn to push changes to an external repository so on `master` again I did:

```
git svn rebase
```

This recovered some of the previously pushed commits from svn.

I then cherry-picked the rest of the most recent commits from the `saved_feature` branch, 
I then did a `git stash pop`, fixed the conflicts that should have been automatically merged, but were not, and finally had my `master` in the state it was originally.

Could anyone point out in this sorry tale where my mental model and git parted ways & how I can avoid getting into messes such as these again?

Answer (score 3):

You were probably working those last 6 days on a [**detached HEAD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009) from an *ancestor* of master HEAD.
(thank you [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen) for suggesting that last part: it explains potentially everything)

Suppose you have:

```
x--x--x--x <- master
      ^
      |
      T1 (tag)
```

If you do a '`git checkout T1`' to see that `T1` content, boom: detached HEAD right there.
If you do some fixes from `T1`, you end up with

```
x--x--x--x <- master
      ^\
      | -y--y--y--y--y--y <- detached HEAD (a dirty, b dirty)
      |
     T1(tag)
```

Now, a `git checkout -b saved_feature` at this point would create a branch with the last 6 (days worth of) commits in it:

```
x--x--x--x <- master
      ^\
      | -y--y--y--y--y--y--a <- saved_feature (a committed, b dirty)
      |
     T1(tag)
```

, but the checkout to `master` is not trivial for file `b`.
And a merge from `master` to `saved_feature` won't be trivial either (certainly not a fast-forward one)

Anyhow, that is why it is important to keep an eye at all time at the [current branch you are actually working in](http://arnorehn.de/cgi-bin/weblog_basic/index.php?p=34).

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using the `__git_ps1` function from git's bash completion (and use the completion too!) instead of that blog post's homegrown solution.

Comment: @Jefromi: I agree. At least that blog post does mention the `__git_ps1 ` function. (even though that other "homegrown" one is nice too: http://asimilatorul.com/index.php/2010/04/13/bash-prompt-with-git-branch-and-status/#readmore-entry100413-221424)

Comment: One possible explanation of why merging *saved_feature* into *master* could be a non-fast-forward merge and have conflicts: The OP detached his HEAD at some ancestor of the tip of *master* (e.g. investigating an old snapshot) and his new changes had conflicts with the state of the tip of *master* (e.g. fixing bugs that were already fixed at the tip of *master*, but in different ways).

Comment: @Chris: very true; I have included that scenario in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm I'm pretty sure I didn't detach my HEAD by checking out old commits, the only thing I've been doing that I can imagine could have detached the head would have been `git svn rebase`

Comment: @EoghanM: and you didn't have any issue during your last "`git svn rebase`" like in this thread? http://us.generation-nt.com/bug-557477-git-svn-git-svn-dcommit-doesnt-handle-network-failure-help-168985541.html

Comment: @EoghanM: Or you didn't '`git checkout svn/trunk`, which would check out a detached head, since `svn/trunk` is a remote. (see this thread: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg133724.html)