# Unable to clone directly into a git tag using -b <tagname>

Tags: git

I'm a bit puzzled why I'm unable to checkout a tag directly from the git clone command. What I try to do is:

```
git clone -b mytag <url>/foo.git
```

The error I get is:

```
warning: Remote branch mytag not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead
```

Tag is present and e.g.

```
cd foo && git checkout mytag
```

...works well.

If anyone could share some light on why it's impossible to clone directly into a tag I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: So, is your question : why that doesn't work ? or What is the best workaround ?

Comment: I guess both questions has been explained here now, although I find the inconsistency a bit confusing. I will keep it up until tomorrow to see if there is some other approaches, then I will close it. Thanks for explanation @mb14, @simplyharsh, @VonC !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps all you really need/want to do is use `git archive` to pull a tarball of anything `git rev-parse` can understand.  You can use the `--remote` option to pull the archive from some remote source identically to the `<url>/foo.git` value that you are passing to clone.  In theory, this will be much quicker since all you will be grabbing is the working tree and not the entire repository.

Here's a "works for me" example:

```
% git archive --prefix foo/ --remote <url>/foo.git my-tag | tar -xf -
```

Comment: I will definitively look into that. The overhead of cloning is probably not worth it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a [detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009) after the git checkout mytag?

It is possible that `mytag` is not in the "`refs/heads/`" namespace (for branche HEADs) of `foo.git`, but still reference a valid commit.

That would explain the warning in `git clone`, while the `git checkout` runs ok.

Comment: Yes, I'm in a detached head. I'm not sure I understand the difference between git checkout and git clone in this case. Would an annotated tag help?

Comment: @grm: no it won't make any difference. the git clone -b is for branch. Any other refspec might be accessible though a `git checkout`, but you will be in a DETACHED HEAD (meaning you will need to create a branch)

Answer (score 0):

-b is meant to checkout a branch not a tag. That's why it's saying remote BRANCH not found ;-)

Comment: Well, git-checkout also calls it a branch, but works on tags so I think the question is valid.

Comment: @grm I m not saying the question is invalid, but just answering the question. Maybe they have implemented it for checkout but not for clone. BTW git checkout -b on tag create a new branch, I'm not really suprised that you can't create a new branch before having finishing cloning the repo.

Comment: AFAIK: There is no new branch crated in any of the examples. It's just a reference.

Comment: @grm, my mistake git checkout -b tagname , doesn't checkout tagname  but just create a new branch with the name : tagname.
So what do you mean by 'git checkout also calls it a branch' ? you can pass any commit to git checkout, but the -b in git-clone and git-checkout have a different meaning (but always refer to a branch, never a tag)

Answer (score 0):

Cloning directly into a tag, beats me intention-wise.

But the command you are using, actually is used to clone repository's branch. So you are actually asking to checkout branch name `mytag` from repository. `mytag` branch is obviously not in your remote repository.

And I don't think there is any direct way to clone into a new tag. You have to clone and then apply tags or fetch the tags of remote repository explicitly using `git fetch --tags $URL`.

**Edit on response:**

Well, deployment from tag is a common usage style. As code is usually tagged once its at a considerable state. You can checkout `mytag` once you cloned and fetched tags from remote repositories.

```
git checkout mytag
```

or even

```
git checkout -b mytagbranch mytag
```

and continue the deployment.

Comment: I'm looking into doing deployment directly from the tag system.