# Move commits from master onto a branch using git

Tags: git, commit, git-branch, git-reset

I'm trying to learn how to use Git effectively and I'm wondering how I should (good practice/bad practice?) solve the following case:

Say I have the following chain of commits in master:

- Initial commit
- Commit 1
- Commit 2
- Commit 3

Then I realize that what's done in the last two commits is completely wrong and I need to start from Commit 1 again. Questions:

- How should I do that?
- Can I move Commit 2 and 3 to a separate branch to keep for future reference (say they weren't that bad after all) and continue working from Commit 1 on master?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
git branch tmp            # mark the current commit with a tmp branch
git reset --hard Commit1  # revert to Commit1
```

The SO answer "[What's the difference between 'git reset' and 'git checkout' in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout-in-git)" is quite instructive for that kind of operation

[image]

A **`git reset --hard HEAD~2`** would do the same thing (without needing to get back the SHA1 for `Commit1` first).

Since `Commit2` and `Commit3` are still reference by a Git ref (here a branch), you can still revert to them anytime you want (`git checkout tmp`).

---

Actually, [Darien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315988/darien) mentions in the comments (regarding moving `Commit2` and `Commit3` to another branch):

> Accidentally committed to the wrong branch, this let me move it, did:

```
git checkout correctbranch
git rebase tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

This works here since the initial branch has been reset to `Commit1`, which means the `git rebase tmp` will replay every commit after `Commit1` (so here  `Commit2` and `Commit3`) to the new '`correctbranch`'.

Comment: Thanks! Just an observation: In gitk the tmp branch doesn't show. Shouldn't it do so, as Commit1 is common for both branches?

Comment: @Paul: did you try a " `gitk --all` "?