# How to move some last Git commits currently on a branch, onto another branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a repository where I had been working on `master` branch having last added some 10 or so commits which I now wish were on another branch, as they describe work that I now consider experimental (I am still learning good Git practices).

In light of this consideration, I would now like to have these last 10 commits form their own branch so to speak, so that I can have `master` clean and reserved for "release" / "stable" commits only.

To illustrate, what I have is:

```
        b--b (feature B)
       /       
X--X--X--Z--Z--Z--Z--Z--Z (master)
    \
     a--a--a (feature A)
```

You can see that commits marked with `X` and `Z` are all on the `master` branch, while what I want is commits marked with `Z` (the now considered experimental "feature Z" work) to lie on their own branch and `master` ending with the rightmost `X`. To illustrate, the desired graph:

```
        b--b (feature B)
       /       
X--X--X (master)
    \  \
     \  Z--Z--Z--Z--Z--Z (feature Z - the new branch I want)
      \
       a--a--a (feature A)
```

That way I will have my `master` reserved for releases and otherwise stable commits, being able to merge in A, B and Z features as needed.

So how do I move the "Z" commits onto their own branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move commits from master onto a branch using git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719068/move-commits-from-master-onto-a-branch-using-git)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git branch feature-Z
git reset <commit_id>
```

where commit_id is an identifier of that last X commit before b branches off.

Comment: You probably want `git reset --hard`. And if there are any modifications that haven’t been checked in, throw in a `git stash` before it and a `git stash pop` after it.

Comment: Agreed, fundamentally.  Since he didn't say/request anything about starting/wished working tree status, I threw in the minimal-typing solution that did what he asked.  He looks like he knows enough git to come up with the details on his own.  I upvoted your comment to help keep it visible for others who wouldn't.

Comment: This left me with an old checkout of master with all the changes in Z uncommitted or untracked. I had to clean them up manually in order to be able to `git checkout feature-Z`.

Comment: @Calimo: If the mixed reset outcome disturbs you, you were a candidate for Aristotle's variant.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, the answer is here - http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset - search for the text "Undo a commit, making it a topic branch" - the example shows making the last 3 commits a branch and resetting master to the commit previous to those 3 commits:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git branch topic/wip
$ git reset --hard HEAD~3
$ git checkout topic/wip
Switched to branch topic/wip
```

Comment: The kernel.org link has since gone 404, but `man git-rebase` will give the latest for your version of git.

Answer (score 2):

Simply rename master and start a new master at the last X:

`git checkout master; git branch -m feature; git checkout -b master HEAD~6`

Comment: one drawback to your proposal is that now feature is tracking origin/master.

Answer (score 0):

Create and checkout in desired new branch
Force master branch N commits back (in your case 10)

```
git checkout -b feature-z
git branch -f master HEAD~10
```