# How to undo git mixed reset?

Tags: git

I ran below command in my working directory.

`git reset`

It printed names of some files like

`M /path/to/file`

From [What does 'git reset' command do without any option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931299/what-does-git-reset-command-do-without-any-option) I understand that `git reset` = `git reset --mixed HEAD`

How do I undo the above operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just did 'git reset' you have just unstaged your files, but you still have your modifications in your working directory. So you didn't lose anything, nor changed anything as you reset to HEAD.

Even if you had done a 'git reset HEAD~2' for example, which would have change your working directory, you could still use the reflog to recover, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: chrs - after an mistaken git mixed reset i've got all my files ready to be staged. i simply want to go back to the further commit as if nothing happened - any idea on how to do this?