# What should RESETING detached HEAD to BRANCH do?

Tags: git, git-reset

If I understand right, when you have a detached head(HEAD->commit), 
then the git CHECKOUT branch solves the issue(HEAD->branch[->someCommit])

But what does resetting to a branch do? It was supposed to set the pointer of an object(often a branch) to which HEAD points to another branch.
But since we dont have this middle-man (branch) - what does it do then? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply moves HEAD: as I mentioned in "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/6309)":

> [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) is all about moving HEAD.

If you move HEAD to another commit, then HEAD remains [detached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

After [a discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74003/discussion-between-novellizator-and-vonc) about the difference between `git reset` and `git checkout` vs the detached or attached nature of the [symbolic reference HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/6309), here what we found together:

- if HEAD points on branch, `git reset` would move branch as well to `<something>`: resetting it doesn't make it un-detached, it changes branch HEAD
- if HEAD points on a commit (was already detached), then it would remain detached: As the OP puts it:

> so when detached and I call `git reset <branch>` it finds the commit behind the branch and change the commit in `.git/HEAD` for the commit that `<branch>` refers to.

Let's consider a HEAD which is attached to branch1 (`cat .git/HEAD` would return `branch1`):

- `git checkout branch2` will change HEAD to `branch2` and leave `branch1` untouched
- `git reset branch2` will reset `branch1` HEAD to `branch2`: `cat .git/refs/heads/branch1` would contains the same SHA1 as `branch2`.

That's the difference:

- reset moves HEAD (as I told at the beginning: it is all about moving HEAD)
- checkout switches branches (or detaches HEAD)

Regarding the attached/detached nature of HEAD:

- reset doesn't change the nature of HEAD (if it was attached, it remains attached)
- checkout can change the nature of HEAD (if it was attached and you checkout a commit instead of a branch, HEAD becomes detached)

Comment: is not checkout also about moving HEAD? To my mind checkout moves the HEAD whereas reset moves the thing HEAD points to...

Comment: As I mentioned in "What's the difference between “`git reset`” and “`git checkout`”?" (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3639387/6309), `git checkout` will modify the working tree (and not the index). `git reset` can move HEAD without modifying the working tree (and it can reset the index as well, if not `--soft`).

Comment: ok. so in detached head, and when we neglect the working tree and the index, then reset branch and checkout branch do essentially the same?(=both move the head to the branch)

Comment: @Novellizator they do the same for HEAD, if you reset or if your checkout a branch. But the fact those commands are applied to a *detached* HEAD is not relevant. They would still do the same if the HEAD was *not* detached.

Comment: well, now I'm getting _really_ confused. In your own post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout/3639387#3639387 you showed a picture and obviously the HEAD was NOT after moved after the reset(.git/HEAD contained the _same_ thing), only the develop was moved. So I conclude that git reset (--soft, for simplification) does _not_ do anything to the HEAD. What am I missing?

Comment: @Novellizator what you are missing is that HEAD is a symbolic ref: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/6309. If it references a branch, then it moves the branch. If it references a commit, it changes commit. In all cases it moves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74003/discussion-between-novellizator-and-vonc).

Comment: One very small addition, to give another perspective: both checkout and reset call internally update-ref, but git checkout calls it with --no-deref.  See more here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/checkout.c#L649