# How to push an older checked out commit to github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I checked out one of my older commits with git checkout. Now I want to push this commit but keep getting errors. After I try to git push:

[image]

I tried:

git push origin HEAD:new branch

But that didn't work. I've tried a lot of combinations of stackoverflow answers but can't figure it out.

Comment: "But that didn't work."  What happened exactly?

Comment: Please don't paste *pictures* of text.  Just paste in the text itself.

Comment: VonC's answer worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a new branch where you are:

```
git checkout -b newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch
```

That will reference the detached HEAD ([since checkout a commit means detached HEAD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639387/6309) and allows you to push said branch.

Comment: Hi VonC, ran into trouble on heroku deploy. It says: remote: Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.

Comment: Now that I'm off the master branch, I guess heroku doesn't know what to do.

Comment: @TyrionLannister true. You can ask a new question to determine how to deal with this situation.