# U-boot source code of specific revision

Tags: git, u-boot

I need to get the U-boot source of the following version details.

```
VERSION = 2014 
PATCHLEVEL = 07 
SUBLEVEL = 
EXTRAVERSION = 
NAME =
```

I tried following steps.

1. Cloned with the following command.

   git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git

But following is the version details.

```
VERSION = 2015
PATCHLEVEL = 10
SUBLEVEL = 
EXTRAVERSION = -rc1
NAME =
```

2. git branch is showing only master branch.

   ```
   user:~/U-boot/u-boot$ git branch
   * master
   user:~/U-boot/u-boot$
   ```

Can you please guide to get the U-boot source(version:2014, patchlevel:07) using git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a tag matching those specifications.
(see [list of tags for `git.denx.de/u-boot.git`](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=tags)).

That means, once you have cloned the repo, you can do a:

```
cd ~/U-boot/u-boot
git checkout v2014.07
```

Note that it will leave you in a detached HEAD mode (see "[What's the difference between “`git reset`” and “`git checkout`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639387/6309)").
But if don't do any commit, this doesn't matter

Comment: @user3693586 Thank you. I asked because I saw most of your questions had no accepted answers.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow from now. How to accept answer which is in comment.