# Difference between git reset --hard <filename> and git checkout -- <filename>

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

As far as I understand, git reset --hard  will update  in the index and working directory to whatever the HEAD points to?

Git checkout --  will update  in working directory to whatever that file state in the INDEX is?

So if  is unstaged, then they will do the same thing (change the file in the working directory to its state in the HEAD/INDEX [which are the same state for that file])? But if it is staged then git reset --hard  will do as above, but Git checkout --  will do nothing?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout

Comment: You might want to clarify your question, perhaps add an example. As formulated, it isn't very clear.

Comment: The biggest difference is that one works, the other does not. You cannot `reset --hard` paths: `git reset --hard <filename>` produces `fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.`

Comment: Yeah that is quite an important difference. I should have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

[`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) expects a [revision/commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), not a [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

> Resets the *index and working tree*. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since *commit* are discarded. [emphasis mine]

If no revision is given, it defaults to `HEAD` (the current commit)

In contrast [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), when called as `git checkout [tree-ish] -- pathspec...`, overwrites the files at the specified path(s) in the working directory and in the index with the content of the blob referenced from the given tree. If no tree is provided, i.e. `git checkout -- pathspec...`, the files in the working directory are overwritten with the current content stored in the index

> Overwrite the contents of the files that match the pathspec. When the *tree-ish* (most often a commit) is *not given*, overwrite working tree *with the contents in the index*. When the *tree-ish* is given, overwrite *both the index and the working tree* with the contents at the *tree-ish*. [emphasis mine]

To mimic the behavior of `reset --hard` (without a revision), you can use `git checkout HEAD -- pathspec...`.

Git 2.25 introduced [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). To get the same behavior with the new command, you'd use `git restore --staged --worktree -- pathspec...` (or `git restore -SW -- pathspec...`)