# GIT - update repo from another repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

**Problem:**

we have 2 repo's. working on repo A and once each X days (or when repo A is stable) we update repo B to be exactly like repo A (excluding some files from repo A)

**Example:**

2 repo's (each with its own git)

```
repoA
+-pom.xml
+-src

repoB
+-pom.xml
+-src
```

want to run a script that will once every X days take all commits from repoA that didnt affect pom.xml and apply them as 1 commit in repo B

eventually repoB src folder should be exactly the same as repoA src folder

thinking of taking the easy path and just using a bash script

```
mkdir /tmp/repoA
cp /repoA /tmp/repoA
rm /tmp/repoA/pom.xml
mv /tmp/repoA repoB
git commit -m "updated repo B"
git push
```

some1 has a better idea doing this using git and not just plain old mv ??

Answer (score 1):

You could simply specify the working tree (of `repoA`) when updating `repoB`:

```
cd /path/to/repoB
git --work-tree=/path/to/repo/A add -A .
git checkout pom.xml
git commit -m "update repo B"
```

Comment: nice! after doing this I want to continue working on repoB , how can i "unset" the --work-tree ?

Comment: @Nimrod007 the work-tree is only set for the `git add` command.

Comment: dont u need to do: git reset HEAD pom.xml ??

Comment: @Nimrod007 no reset: checkout, in order to restore the content of pom.xml as in master branch. You want to update the working tree, not just the index: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3639387/6309