# Git checkout without committing

Tags: git

Is it necessary to commit to git repository before checkout? I've heard it is, because I can lose the changes. However, after modifying a file and checking out, I could easily come back to my previous branch and I didn't lose any work. The file had M status.

They state [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/#Git_checkout_without_committing_WITH_a_conflict) that `M` means Merged (that's weird, I think it notifies me about modifications).

```
$ git checkout master
M   README
Switched to branch 'master'
$ cat README
This is the README file.
This line was added in the working directory while in the test branch.
```

From 'Git Checkout Without Committing: WITHOUT A Conflict' section.
What does `M README` mean?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `git checkout` won't process if any current modification could be erased.

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/book/01-introduction/images/areas.png]

<sup>(image from "[Getting Started - Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)")</sup>

The [example mentioned](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/#Git_checkout_without_committing_WITH_a_conflict) actually uses [`git checkout -m`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (and no commit), which means the modification is merged:

```
-m
--merge
```

> When switching branches, **if you have local modifications to one or more files that are different between the current branch and the branch to which you are switching, the command refuses to switch branches** in order to preserve your modifications in context.
>
> **However, with this option, a three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch is done**, and you will be on the new branch.

It is best to commit (or to stash) current changes before a checkout, but `checkout -m` can at least merge those changes instead of failing (or erasing them in case of `checkout -f` (see also "[What's the difference between “git reset” and “git checkout”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639342/6309)").

> What does M README mean

That is the unstaged (and uncommitted) modification, the work in progress.
A `git checkout -m` allows for that modification to be merged in the destination branch, instead of making a simple `git checkout` fail.
See also "[What’s In The Index? What’s Changed?](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/whats-in-the-index-whats-changed/)".

[image: https://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0201-tn.png]

Comment: @user107986 that is the idea: add a conflict in the test branch before a `git checkout -m master`: the change is merged, and the merge conflict is shown.

Comment: Deleted comment and put it in the question.