# What is the difference between "git reset --hard HEAD~1" and "git checkout ."?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-reset

I'm currently learning git, and I have issue what exactly do these commands do?

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1

git checkout .
```

What's the difference between the two? They both permanently delete the last commit, as I understand. I think that there is a deep difference, so I hope for a clear explanation because I'm a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "git reset" and "git checkout"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout)

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`: Permanently removes the last commit and all uncommitted changes.

`git checkout .`: Discards changes in the working directory and restores it to the state of the last commit without affecting commit history.

Comment: Is `git reset --hard HEAD` more similar to `git checkout .`?

Comment: No, `git reset --hard HEAD` affects the entire repository, resetting all changes in all files and commits.
`git checkout .` affects only the current directory and its subdirectories, discarding changes in those specific files.

Comment: You say no, but your explanation makes it sound like they're the same if `$PWD` is the repo root.

Comment: yes in that case they are same.

Comment: `git checkout .` will *not* discard staged changes. So it does not necessarily restore the working directory to the state of the last commit.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

makes your current branch/HEAD move to the **previous commit**.
`--hard` discards changes to tracked files, including staged changes.
(As this operation moves HEAD, an entry in `git reflog` is created)

```
git checkout .
```

discards **unstaged** changes from tracked files in the current directory tree.
This means: Staged changes will be kept on top of **current commit**!
To also discard staged changes you have to specify the commit to check out, e.g. HEAD: `git checkout HEAD .` - which will behave similar to `git reset --hard HEAD` (no `~1`!) - if run in top directory of the repo.