# Simpler explanation of path for GIT checkout command

Tags: git, git-checkout

In the [git documentation for the checkout command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) the following text is found:

> ...If no paths are given,
>   git checkout will also update HEAD to
>   set the specified branch as the
>   current branch....

Can anyone give a simpler explanation of what this means? I'm sorry if it seems simple, and reading through that page, I can't seem to come up with what it means exactly. Sorry if this seems basic..

In particular I am confused on how checkout is updating HEAD. I usually envision checkout affecting the working directory -- is this an ability unique to git in that you are updating your local copy of the repository for the purposes of working with it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Version A:** (specifying *only* the branch)

```
git checkout <branch>
```

Gets *all* files for that <branch> and places HEAD (a pointer to "where am I now") at the branch specified.

**Version B:** (specifying a path *only*)

```
git checkout <file>
```

Gets the latest version of <file> and leaves HEAD alone.

Comment: It has been a long time since this question and I understand GIT much, much better. I prefer this answer, because it is written clearly and concisely (though I did update it, mostly for formatting) I believe at the time I had a misunderstanding that HEAD was the revision -- I didn't understand that HEAD was a pointer. I was thinking of SVN where saying HEAD usually meant I ended up at a particular revision in my workspace.

Comment: would you say it's similar to an `svn revert` ?

Answer (score 3):

`HEAD` is a pointer to the commit your working copy was checked out from. so if you checkout a branch (or commit or tag) then `HEAD` is set to that commit.

this information is stored in the textfile `.git/HEAD`, you can simply look at its content:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
# refs: refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that `git checkout branchname` will

1. Check out the files from the tip of that branch into your working directory, and
2. Set your `HEAD` to the tip of that branch, so that you are now "on" it.

Example:

```
 jb@apto % git branch         
 * develop
   master
   next
 jb@apto % git checkout master
 Switched to branch 'master'
 jb@apto % git branch
   develop
 * master
   next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) mode (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009)), you could easily reset HEAD to the master branch:

[image: checkout detached]

Here a '`git checkout`' would reset HEAD to the tip of `master` branch.
(More in "[A Visual Git Reference](http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/)")
It will also update both the index and the working directory.
So it is not just about resetting the pointer '`HEAD`'.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.23+ (August 2019), use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of the [confusing `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), coupled with [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) (for files only)

```
git switch master
```

That would switch HEAD back to `master`.

You can still reference a commit directly (detached HEAD) with `git switch --detach <acommit>`.
No more checkout (which deals both with branches and files).