# Deleted files locally but cannot push changes to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, push

I had some files that were messing up my Heroku app so I decided to delete them locally.  When I tried to push the changes to Heroku, it says that the files were deleted but there were no changes to commit.  Also when I ran git push heroku master, it said everything was up to date although my commit showed that there were deleted files.  How can I push these changes or delete them from the repository?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without giving more information, it is hard to solve this problem. What is the output of `git status`. In a normal situation, removing files should not give any problem, so maybe give us the steps you have done (the commands you have executed).

Answer (score 3):

i fixed this same problem with

```
git commit -a
```

Answer (score 2):

> I ran git push heroku master, it said everything was up to date although my commit showed that there were deleted files

That does smell like a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009) mode, where you are making commits without being in any branch.
Check what `git branch --all` returns