# git "lost" my commit, sort of, log giving conflicting results

Tags: git, commit

Something really strange here I cannot figure out.

Last night I committed some files.

About lunch time today I realised that the files has "lost" all the changes I'd committed yesterday.

I went back through the git log results and sure enough the commit was there. I checked the contents by doing a git diff and the commit contains the changes. However ....

If I do a git log I can see the commit in the list of all commits. If I do a commit log on one of the files in the commit, I see every commit except the one from last night. If I do a git show to display the files in the commit the specific file is there. Sooooo

git log - shows the commit
git show - shows the files in the commit
git log file - list every commit but the one I'm interested in !!

I also cannot figure out how to tell what killed the committed changes.

Anyone got any clues? I like git, but it's a real pain in the rear to figure out sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a git checkout on the directory and see if that has any effect. If that doesn't update them, delete them and then do a git checkout on the files.

Comment: I gave up and cut and pasted the mods from the diff. Probably there is an easier way to do it, but I didn't have time to ind it :-)

Comment: The way I mentioned above is the easiest way while keeping everything consistent as git checkout gets a clean copy of the file in question from the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't committed those files while being on a **[detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009)**.
(`git branch --all` would not mention any current branch)

[image: detached head]

The commit would be there, but not accessible from a branch.

Comment: Nope, we are working on master only. The really weird thing is that of the 3 files in the commit, one files changes did stick and the other two's didn't.