# Can't commit files with Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, egit

Whenever I try to commit a file EGit says "no files to commit", though the file is staged for commit according to its icon in Project Explorer (see the image)

[image]

This happens to any file in my project. What am I doing wrong? I'm using EGit 0.11.1.

**EDIT:**

Updated to 1.2.0 and it worked, thank you all!

Comment: You may also want to consider upgrading your EGit version. Current release version is 1.1.0, and since 0.11.1 many bugs were fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the [OP asd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249230/asd), EGit0.11.1 is [not the latest version](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F):
The Egit 1.2-SNAPSHOT (available through the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/)) solves the problem.

> In general EGit promises to support at least the latest two Eclipse releases (as of this writing in Oct 2011 this is 3.6.2 "Helios SR2" and 3.7.1 "Indigo SR1").

---

For reference, my original answer was:

It is possible, as shown in [bug 341679](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341679) to checkout a remote branch (or a tag), without creating a local branch.
If you are in this situation, then you are working in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009), which would explain the "no files to commit" message.

See "[Git Lesson: Be mindful of a detached head](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/29/life-lesson-be-mindful-of-a-detached-head/)" for more, and check if your history doesn't display a HEAD pointer:

[image: no head]

> The good news is that you can quickly fix this problem by creating a new branch.
>   In egit, this is as simple as `Team -> Switch To -> New Branch`. Now, all these ‘detached commits’ will live on the new branch (new_idea).

[image: new branch]

Comment: Unfortunately this it not my case, I do have a local branch (created outside of Eclipse), but thanks anyway. BTW the problem is gone after an update to 1.2.0.

Comment: @asd Ok. I have included your conclusion in this answer.