# Update changes from Bitbucket to local git repository in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket

I have a repository on bitbucket and I was able to successfully import the repository to Eclipse to work on the java files but I've run into a problem. I can't seem to update Eclipse to accommodate for the commits made to the Bitbucket git repository. I've tried to import again and and I used pull but none of the changes appear on eclipse. When I try import it says the .project file already exists in the directory. When I use pull it says everything is up to date so I figured I'm using pull incorrectly. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should precise more details to get an answer.

If you did all the steps correctly, for example from this tutorial:
http://crunchify.com/how-to-configure-bitbucket-git-repository-in-you-eclipse/
you won't have problems.

Try to delete all the files from the folder that you have imported, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try import it says the .project file already exists in the directory

That is expected: you would need to delete the project from the eclipse workspace (not from the disk) to reimport it again. But its content would be identical.

Check a git status on the command line to see if you are on a branch or in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).
You can also see it in the [history view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7952342/6309) of eclipse.
A detached HEAD would explain why a pull doesn't refresh anything.