# import all branches from github

Tags: git, egit

I set up egit to work with my GitHub repo on my university computer.
The repo has 5 branches including master and my local copy also has those branches so I can go to `Team -> Switch to` and select the desired branch in eclipse.

On my laptop I set up Egit and cloned the repo.
I selected all branches when importing however under Local in the git repositories tab it only has master, all the other branches are under Remote Tracking.
If I switch to a Remote Tracking branch make a change, commit and then push I get the following error:

```
An internal Exception occurred during push: Nothing to push.
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: did u try using --force?

Comment: Where is that option in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I switch to a Remote Tracking branch make a change, commit and then push I get the following error

You didn't create a local branch from your remote tracking branch you just switch to.
That means you are in a [detached `HEAD` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes), hence the "nothing to push".
See "[Git Lesson: Be mindful of a detached head](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/29/life-lesson-be-mindful-of-a-detached-head/)":

(No `HEAD`:)

[image: no head]

```
Team -> Switch To -> New Branch
```

will be enough to fix the issue, and then push it to the remote.

(`HEAD` on the new branch:)

[image: HEAD on the new branch]