# Egit unable to push to upstream and unable to update code from upstream

Tags: git, egit

I am facing problem with eclipse git plugin (EGIN)

I am using Eclipse Indigo v.

I have checkout project from git repo, if i made change in one file and try to commit first and after commit when i try to push it to upstream it does not show any change to push to upstream...

Another problem i am facing is if developer have push changes i pull from upstream it should download and merged files but it won't and when i do synchronzie it keep showing files in red.

Not every time facing this issue, randomly it happens and it won't work normally until i delete my local repo and fetch contents again from remote repo.

anybody can refer any good tutorial how can i push and pull changes ??

Comment: When that happens, are you in a detached HEAD mode? (http://swik.net/Eclipse/Planet+Eclipse/Ian+Bull%3A+Git+Lesson%3A+Be+mindful+of+a+detached+head/fij8f)

Comment: (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9273805/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files will be shown in red when there are any issues with merging. Otherwise the changes will be merged automatically and you will not see any issues.

When git fails to merge the files automatically, it will highlight the files in red, and you need to resolve the conflicts, merge them manually and commit the changes, and push to upstream.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide

Comment: nice, Merge does not mean auto merge, we've to do it manually! I used to stuck at this, until i changed from using merge strategy to `git rebase`