# Git push fails because everything is alledgely up-to-date

Tags: git, push

I have some weird problem using git. I have added and commited my changes. But when pushing to the remote repo  : I am told everything is uptodate but it is not. I tried to follow the indications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes), but it is still not working, it doesn't seems I have to deal with a detached head. (For informations, the branch I am dealing with is used to push on to seperate remotes). Does anybody has an idea ?

Comment: do you specify the remote server to push to? For example, `git push remoterepo master` where `remoterepo` is the name of the remote repository and `master` is the name of th branch you want to push.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to specify the name of the remote where so push your changes.

I.e., in `.git/config` it should be like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://git.company-repo.com/repo.git

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: In fact I used git remote set-head origin mybranch and then I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote -v
```

Look at the output for the link that has (push) in it, e.g.

```
origin  git@github.com:username/repo_name.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/repo_name.git (push)
```

If this is not the case, you'll need to add a remote by doing the following command:

```
git remote add [repo_name] git@github.com:username/repo_name.git
```

Then try `git pull`