# How to actually sync local git repo and remote git repo that show up as synced but have different contents

Tags: git, synchronization

My problem is this: I am using Git for source control of a project with several developers. My local master branch and the remote master branch appear as synced: doing git push, git pull and git fetch do nothing except showing "everything up to date" messages. But, when I access the remote repository, the content for the file involved is different than the file I have here on my project.

Ideally what I want is to somehow force my local repo to download the remote file from the remote repo and overwrite the local copy. Then I could just reapply the missing commits and do a new push.

Anyone ever have a similar problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git push says everything up-to-date even though I have local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes)

Comment: I'd say it could be any number of things; but to start diagnosing, I would run `git status` (as this will confirm what's checked out and what its upstream relationship (if any) is), and `git remote -v` to verify your local repo's relationship to the remote