# "git push" to remote shows "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: git

I have a branch tracking to remote repository. 
(the remote repository is a forked version of the origin) 
It has local commits while when I try to git push, it shows "Everything up-to-date".
Is there anything wrong?
Thanks!

Here's my workflow:

```
git remote add kai_fork git@192.168.200.1:kai_wang/my_project.git
git remote update
git checkout -b k-dev kai_fork/backend_dev
... (edit and git commit to local kai_dev branch)
```

[image]

```
git remote show kai_fork
```

partial results:
[image]

Comment: Per `git help push`, `-n` means "Do everything except actually send the updates."

Comment: @wjandrea, yes I know -n means dry run. if something "could" be push, the message will be different from "Everything up-to-date". -n option won't affect the result message.

Comment: Oh, I see. Voting to reopen. But why are you using `-n` in the first place? Also please put the output in the question as text - helps with readability, copy-pasting, etc.

Comment: Check out [git push says “everything up-to-date” even though I have local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/999907/4518341). There are lots of different answers.

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea, the link really helps.  In my case I have to use "git push kai_fork k-dev:backend_dev".

Answer (score 1):

Just try to run this command to push,

```
git push
```

And for checking the status of the remote. Try this,

```
git status
```

Comment: The result of "git push" is the same as "git push -n" => "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: And the result of "git status" is:
On branch k-dev
Your branch is ahead of 'kai_fork/backend_dev' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean