# GitLab CI/CD With Terraform

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I followed this link: https://spacelift.io/blog/gitlab-terraform so I can run my terraform code through a GitLab pipeline. (I should mention I do not have GitLab Premium).

I created a project in GitLab and cloned the project to VS code. The folder are showing and I created three files: main.tf, variables.tf and provider.tf (as per the guide in the link above). I saved the file and I ran 'git commit' but I can't see the terraform files in my GitLab account.

Error message in GitLab> Project> Build> Jobs

ERROR: No files to upload
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I suspect it's because the terraform code on my local machine hasn't been pushed to my GitLab repo. This is the part I'm struggling with.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your commit to the gitlab repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Try typing git push and follow the instructions printed on the command line.

Comment: I tried git push and I get this 'Everything up-to-date'

I check my GitLab repo and the terraform code isn't there

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes it might help you figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Terraform state from gitlab,
You need to configure a backend service in your terraform project.
Terraform state files are plain text, so all sensitive information will be revealed.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html