# How to push to Gitlab after Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a stage at the end of my pipeline job which has to push changes back to a particular Gitlab branch. After trying out several solutions proposed on stackoverflow, I am still not able to push to the branch

```
sh("git add .")
sh("git commit -a -m ' New changes'")
sh('git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@<REPO> ')
```

I expected it to be pushed to the branch which it checked out from but I get the following result on the console

- git commit -a -m ' New changes'
  [detached HEAD bc78567]  New changes
- Everything up-to-date

any reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a detached HEAD in your local repo clone because the commit you are trying to push is not a branch head. Check this link out and you may have to run some commands on jenkins node to get it to sync up with the branch.
[In gitk, why is my yellow button above master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896832/in-gitk-why-is-my-yellow-button-above-master)